# DB2 UDF Permissions

Tags: permissions, db2, database

I have a custom function that I'm working on... the problem I'm having is simple: Permssions.

[example function:](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/db2/udfarea.html)

```
drop function circle_area
go

CREATE FUNCTION  circle_area (radius FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
     DECLARE pi FLOAT DEFAULT 3.14;
     DECLARE area FLOAT;

     SET area =  pi * radius * radius;
     RETURN area;
END
GO
```

if I then log out of my "admin" account... and log into test account I get a "Not authorized" error when I try to run something "Select circle_area(foo) from library.bar".

I can log into iSeries Navigator, navigate to schema > functions > permissions and change the permission for public from Exclude to All. bam it works.

How do I grant permission to all, either in the CREATE FUNCTION or after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `GRANT` statement:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION CIRCLE_AREA TO PUBLIC;
```